# Why is python running so slow on my Surface Book 2

Tags: python, windows, performance

I have a new Surface Book 2 with Windows Build 18.09 on it. The processor is an i7 8.th generation (8 cores) and it has 16 GB of RAM.

When I run any type of Python Code, the performance is unbearibly slow. I really do not think it is normal Python performance on this Laptop due to the following reasons:

- the resource monitor shows 5% processor usage for any python code I run. Considering 8 cores being 100%, the python process should definitely use 12,5%.
- I have another Windows 2-1 tablet (Miix 520) that has an i7 7th generation processor and that is normally throattling a lot. Still this tablet runs the same python code with the same python interpreter around 60% faster - not to speak of my Linux laptop with i7 7th generation running the code around 4-5 times faster.

I have no clue what I can do to get appropriate python performance. One comment I found elsewhere was the explanation that Windows Defender is slowing down python processes. I can not deactivate it because it is a working computer that is partially managed by IT. However, I can blacklist folders and files which I did for the whole Anaconda folder - I use Anaconda in order to manage python environments on Windows - and for python.exe. Unfortunately, this did not bring any improvements.

Does anyone has any experiences / explanations for such low performance of python on Windows (or the Surface Book 2 in particular)? Does any one have suggestions what could be done in order to get "normal" python performance?

Comment: Are you using python 32 or 64? And which version?

Comment: Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Comment: I really do not see the reason to downgrade such type of question. To give a comment in such a case would have been honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Windows Defender is slowing down the execution of of python processes.

Blacklisting `python.exe` and the folder from where I execute my script in Windows Defender leads to a significant performance boost.

Another reason, I found out about, is that Windows seems to have lower disc access rates than Linux. This was significant in my case because I processed 50.000 images.